# Naming convention for components which could share the name of an HTML element?

Tags: html, naming-conventions, vue.js

In my Vue project I have a component which acts as a site header, and a component which acts as a site footer.

I can't use these as `<header>` and `<footer>` of course, because these are already HTML elements.

Is there a naming convention that suits this situation? So far, I've been using something like `<site-header>`, because it's just adding a prefix for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix might be added for sake of it. But its a good practice as per [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#concepts) rules and also stated in Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html):

> Note that Vue does not enforce the W3C rules for custom tag names (all-lowercase, must contain a hyphen) though following this convention is considered good practice.

This is what I prefer:
If at all your component is application specific, it should have an application specific name.

If its a component which can be used across, the name should be based on its feature. For eg `<credit-card></credit-card>`

So its a good practice to follow this naming convention and it also helps in differentiating custom elements from the standard ones.